# How to process image in android for tensorflow lite input?

Tags: java, python, android, machine-learning, tensorflow-lite

**What I Did?**

I am working on image classification problem. I have trained my CNN model in python and then converted it into Tensorflow-Lite for my android app. I have tested my tensorflow-lite model in python and compared my results with my keras model results. Both are same which mean my conversion to Tensorflow lite is correct.

In python my code for reading image is as below. I am not doing any normalization or any other operation on this image. just resizing it and predicting it.

```
image_array_abnormal = np.array([resize(imread('/content/path/abnormal2.png'), (137, 310, 3))])
```

The image_array_shape is:

```
(1, 137, 310, 3)
```

Below are my input and output details of tensorflow lite:

[image]

**Problem**

But when I try to use my model in android, it does not give expected accuracy. I think there is problem with my image or input data to tensorflow lite model.
In android I am just reading image from drawable, using opencv, storing it in Mat, converting it into bitmap and passing it in tensorflow for prediction as below:

```
Mat src = Utils.loadResource(this, R.drawable.abnormal2);
Bitmap dst = Bitmap.createBitmap(src.width(), src.height(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

classifier = new Classifier(activity, "model.tflite", "labels.txt");
results = classifier.recognizeImage(dst);
```

For Classifier class i am following [Tensorflow android demo](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/blob/master/lite/examples/image_classification/android/app/src/main/java/org/tensorflow/lite/examples/classification/tflite/Classifier.java) classifier class.

**What Help I need?**

1. Now How should I process my image that i should became same input as
   in python?
2. Do I have to convert it into array as in python?
3. Do I have to reshape it to (1, 137, 310, 3)?
4. Do I have to create 4D array?
5. How I will get pixel values of images?
6. Do I have to extract RGB pixel values and then change it into 3D array or something?

I am very confused. I know I am doing mistake in image input but what is the right way? How actually I have to process my image to use it as an input to my model?

Comment: Have you seen ALL the Classifier.java file? At the bottom there is a loadImage function that does specific calculations for prepearing bitmap to TensorImage. Inside there there is crop, resize and rotate.... If anything of those is wrong...then you will have weird results!. So answer me that question and I will post an answer how to manipulate correctly

Comment: Yes I have seen that loadimage function. I dont have to normalize or rotate or crop my image that's why I didn't use that function.

Comment: I am sorry, you did not mention about not using the method. I think you are at the right point...the bitmap is not loaded correctly to run inference. If it is possible upload the link of the project to debug.

Comment: I have solved my problem to some extent. No the only issue is that accuracy is not exactly same. Though it is near to original accuracy. how to solve that?

Comment: We have to reproduce....

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you train the image classification yourself in Python. If you have full access to the training dataset, I'd recommend using TF Lite Model Maker and ML Model  Binding to train and integrate the TF Lite model to your Android app. I'll be much easier than the current path. Check out this video.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s_XOVkjXQbU&t=540s

Back to your question, there are several reasons that can cause the issues:

1. Incorrect normalization. It's not clear from model if it's a float or a quantized model, and if it requires normalizing to [-1, 1] or [0, 1] or [0, 255]. You may need  to update the parameters on this [class](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/blob/3fa70c493999e348c4458f3d3b7ba3a747a6b9cc/lite/examples/image_classification/android/app/src/main/java/org/tensorflow/lite/examples/classification/tflite/ClassifierFloatMobileNet.java#L64) to make it work.
2. Image ratio issue: Your image is very wide but most image classification model are trained with square image, so accuracy can drop as the image is resized.

Comment: It is a float model. I didn't normalize my image in python. Trained my model on images with out normalization. So I thought normalization will also not be required in android.

Comment: Can you try using Model Maker and ML Model Binding as in the video above instead of writing your own training code?

It's unusual to not normalize the input image when you train the model so I suspect that there's a discrepancy between pre-processing in your training vs. on your Android app.

Comment: That version of android studio is only for MAC. I don't have MAC. Actually my images were signals. These signals were converted into clip and were normalized. after normalization we saved them. images are already normalized. we don't need to normalize them in python or in android.

Comment: Android Studio is cross-platform. You can download the Android Studio 4.1 Beta 1 for Windows or Linux and it will have the same feature.